# Creating a CSS drop-down menu with a search box the pops down from the search icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a CSS hover drop-down menu. I have a search icon that has a hover on it also. When you hover over the icon it drops down an input for a search.  However when the mouse moves off the area the search box disappears. Looking to keep the box there as long as the cursor is inside the input field, or the input is focused.

If you need me to post what I have just let me know, but it's basically just this with a standard pure CSS hover drop-down, this is the basic HTML setup:

```html
<li class="search">
    <ul class="search">
        <li><input placeholder="enter search" action=""></li>
```

So it works but as I stated when you move off, even with the cursor flashing it will hide again. I'm assuming I'll need some sort of JavaScript to make this work, but not sure where to start with that.

Comment: Fairly sure this isn't possible with CSS only. You'd need a parent selector since the input descends from the element whose visibility you want to control. If the effect was triggered by a click instead, you could perhaps make something work.

Comment: I agree w/ @stevelove, you're gonna need more than just CSS if you want it exactly how you stated. I'm sure there is a jQuery plugin out there to suit what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add and remove a class to the `li` using JavaScript. The code below is in `jQuery` though.

```
        $( ".search" ).onmouseenter( function() {
            $( "input" ).addClass( "seeMe" ).focus();
        });

        $( "input" ).blur( function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "seeMe" );
        });
```

This makes the input visible and gives it focus when you hover the search `li` and hides when the input loses focus.

See a modified version of this on my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wh1t3w0lf21/dXgzn/).

Comment: Probably because I'm a total noobie, but I'm having trouble implementing this.  I looks like it is perfect for what I want.  What is the "seMee" , the newly created .class?

Comment: yes. seeMe would be a class with styling for the input when it is visible. initially the input should have a display: none; and the seeMe class would have display: block; or whatever your want.

Comment: see my jsFiddle to see exactly how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

## Pure CSS Solution

No need for JavaScript to do that. Use plain CSS. I will be using `O` as the search icon. I have also bordered elements for visualizing their collision boxes.

Check out the **Further Reading** section at the bottom of this answer for more clarification.

### Solution

```css
.search {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*border added to visualise collision box*/
}

.search-bar {
  display: none;
}

.search-icon {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*border added to visualise collision box*/
}

.search-icon:hover+.search-bar {
  display: block;
}

.search-bar:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="search">
  <li class="search-icon">O</li>
  <li class="search-bar"><input placeholder="enter search" action=""></li>
</ul>
```

### Animated Solution

```css
.search {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*border added to visualise collision box*/
}

.search-bar {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.search-icon {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*border added to visualise collision box*/
}

.search-icon:hover+.search-bar {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100px;
}

.search-bar:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="search">
  <li class="search-icon">O</li>
  <li class="search-bar">
    <input placeholder="enter search" action="">
  </li>
</ul>
```

## Further Reading

- Check out [CSS Selectors - Combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators),
- [Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) &
- [Adjacent sibling conbinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) on MDN